# Conditional probability of sign(X) given |X|

Tags: probability

Let X $\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. What is the probability $P\bigg(sign(X) =-1 \bigg\vert |X|\bigg)$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: This has the feel of a homework problem. If it is then it might be better to give more context to ensure that the answers provided actually help.

Comment: Let $L(X_1)$ denote the likelihood that $X=X_1$. Then I believe that the answer is $\frac {L(-|X|)}{L(-|X|)+L(|X|)}$

Answer (score 1):

We're going to solve this for a general random variable $X$ with density $f(x)$. We will then find the explicit expression in our particular case as an example.

By assumption, $|X|$ has density $\rho(y) = f(y) + f(-y)$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Using  the definition of conditional expectation, we need to find a function $h$ defined on the nonnegative reals, such that

$$ (*) \quad E [  g(|X|) {\bf 1}_{\{\mbox{sign}(X)\}}(-1) ] = E[  g(|X|)h(|X|) ],$$

for any continuous and bounded $g$. Once we do that,

$$ E[ {\bf 1}_{\{\mbox{sign}(X)\}}(-1) | |X|] = h(|X|),\mbox{ a.s.}$$

To find the function, observe that the lefthand side of $(*)$ is equal to

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 g(|x|)f(x) dx=\int_0^\infty g(|x|) f(-|x|)dx = \int_0^\infty g(y) \frac{f(-y)}{\rho(y)} \rho(y)dy=E[ g(|X|) \frac{f(-|X|)}{\rho(|X|)}].$$

Concluding, for any random variable with density $f$, we have

$$\boxed{ E[ {\bf 1}_{\{\mbox{sign}(X)\}}(-1) | |X|] = \frac{f(-|X|)}{f(|X|)+f(-|X|)},\mbox{ a.s.}}$$

Going back to our particular example, the conditional expectation is

$$ \frac{f(-|X|)}{f(|X|)+f(-|X|)} = \frac{e^{-(|X|+\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}}{e^{-(|X|+\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}+ e^{-(|X|-mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}}=\boxed{\frac{1}{1+e^{2|X|\mu/\sigma^2}}}.$$

This is consistent with our intuition: when $\mu$ is positive, then the conditional probability that the sign is $-1$ is less than $1/2$ and decays with $|X|$, and when $\mu$ is negative then the conditional probability is larger than $1/2$ and increases with $|X|$. The special case $\mu = 0$ is trivial due to the symmetry of $X$ in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This conditional probability can be calculated as
$$
\mathsf{P}(X<0\mid |X|=x)=\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0}\frac{1}{1+\varphi(x,\epsilon)}=\frac{1}{1+e^{2x\mu/\sigma^2}}, \quad x>0,
$$
where
$$
\varphi(x,\epsilon):=\frac{\mathsf{P}(X\in [x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon])}{\mathsf{P}(X\in [-x-\epsilon,-x+\epsilon])}.
$$

Comment: Note that P(|X|=x) =0

Comment: @fweefwfw What is your comment supposed to mean?

Comment: |x| has a folded normal distribution. Hence by Bayes formula you would divide by zero

Comment: @fweefwfw Do you know the meaning of $\mathsf{P}(X<0\mid |X|)$?

Comment: Yes, but consider your first expression P(X<0 | |X|=x) this is equal to P(X<0, |X|=x)/P(|X|=x) and P(|X|=x)=0

Comment: The probability of the event X<0 given the the sigma-algebra generated by |X|

Comment: Formally, it should be the random variable $E( 1_{X<0} |\; |X|)$. This is easily verified to be the constant variable $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @fweefwfw OK. So there exists a Borel function $m(x)$ s.t. $m(|X|)=\mathsf{P}(X<0\mid |X|)$. This function is typically denoted as $\mathsf{P}(X<0\mid |X|=x)$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Unfortunately, this cannot be easily verified; see the deleted answer and the related comments.

Comment: Oh, I see... our distribution isn't symmetric. Well, that's much worse, then.